# Fullcalendar (full calendar) Not defaulting to display the current today's date. Month shows february and not today's

Tags: jquery, date, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to get the calendar to invoke the today function or to set the date to the current date. When the calendar first loads it shows the calendar month to be february. There is a button you can click called 'today' which will switch the date to today's date. I would like to invoke this function or to set the current date to today's date.

documentation of the jquery plugin can be found if you google Adam Shaw fullcalendar jquery plugin. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/. As you can see his example is set to the current today's date.

My code is as follows:

```
    //Loads Fullcalender in Head  use  <div id='calendar'></div> to display
function render_calendar(){
//Calendar [1]
?>  
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php $calendar = "#"; ?>
<?php $calendar .= get_option('fc_option_calendar'); ?>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function


$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('<?php echo $calendar ?>').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today, agenda',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
            ignoreTimezone: false           
        },
         // Multiple Sources
        eventSources: [
        '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed1'); ?>',
        '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed2'); ?>',
        '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed3'); ?>'
        ],        
        events: {
            //http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/centre.edu_5f119bnujdfol3gs59h0driv9c%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic
            //url: '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed1'); ?>',
            className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
            currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago', // an option!           
        },
            month: true,
            week: true,
            day: true,
            agenda: true,
            basic: true,
            //showAgendaButton: true            
    });
});
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

Comment: soo.. have you tried putting what was inside the click event to the initial load of the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the [month](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/month/) option you are setting, it is used to set

> The initial month when the calendar loads.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('<?php echo $calendar ?>').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today, agenda',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
            ignoreTimezone: false           
        },
        // Multiple Sources
        eventSources: [
            '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed1'); ?>',
            '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed2'); ?>',
            '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed3'); ?>'
        ],        
        events: {
            //http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/centre.edu_5f119bnujdfol3gs59h0driv9c%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic
            //url: '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed1'); ?>',
            className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
            currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago', // an option!           
        },
        week: true,
        day: true,
        agenda: true,
        basic: true,
        //showAgendaButton: true            
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ECjAN/) 
With Month: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ECjAN/5/)

Answer (score 0):

On page load after loading calendar just invoke the given function....

.fullCalendar( 'today' );

This will switch your calendar to current date.

Have a look here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/today/

Or you can also load Initial month and date while invoking the calendar on page load. Just remove month: true, while loading calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#cal').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next today, agenda',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
        ignoreTimezone: false           
    },
    // Multiple Sources
    eventSources: [
        'test'
    ],        
    events: {
        //http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/centre.edu_5f119bnujdfol3gs59h0driv9c%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic
        //url: '<?php echo get_option('fc_option_feed1'); ?>',
        className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
        currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago', // an option!           
    },
    week: true,
    day: true,
    agenda: true,
    basic: true,
    //showAgendaButton: true            
});
```

});